# MATLAB query about writing results to text file

Tags: matlab, file-io

I have a question about outputting some results to a text file in MATLAB. Essentially I have read in data from 50000 files (numbered sequentially from 1 to 50000) and I have plotted it. Only those files which meet a certain condition are plotted. I now want to add some code which will allow me to write text to a data file. The specific text I want to write is the file numbers (from 1 to 50000) which meet the certain condtions and have been plotted.

When I try and do this the plots work fine but the text file only contains the last file number. For example if the last file number to fulfil the conditions to be plotted is 50000, then the text file only contains 50000. I am unsure how to change the code - any help/advice/tips would be appreciated.

```
start_sim=1;  
end_sim=50000;  
h = zeros (1,10000);  
for i=start_sim:end_sim  
a=int2str(i);  
File =strcat('result_', 'simulation', '_', a, 'I_byCal_totale.out');
est_tot=importdata(File, '\t', 1);
cal_tot=est_tot.data;
magnitude=1;
t1=cal_tot(:,1)+1750;
model=cal_tot(:,3)+cal_tot(:,5);
if (model(211)>=25)
if (model(211)<=150)
h(a)=plot(t1,model);
xlim([1910 1970]);
ylim([0 500]);
hold all
clickableLegend(h(a),a,'Location','BestOutside')

%Generate OutputFile
fid = fopen('Modeloutputs.in','w+'); 

%Generate some text to write in the file (e.g. the simulation number)
% Print the text in the file
fprintf(fid,h(a),'\t','\n');
%close the file
fclose(fid);

end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
fid = fopen('Modeloutputs.in','a+');
```

should do your job. Your initial attempt using `'w+'` will

> Delete the contents of an existing
>   file or create new file, and open it
>   for reading and writing.

as the documentation says. Another option is to move `fopen` & `fclose` outside of your loop which I would favor.

Comment: Thanks Zellus - can I troulbe you again. I implemented your advice. Although I have put in a '\t' symbol when I run the code all the file numbers are joined together. For example - if I run simulation for file 26000 to 26005, then the text file I have created only looks like this: 260002600126002260032600426005. Is there any way of having each file number on a separate line?

Comment: @mp7: try something similar to fprintf(fid,'%f\n',h(a)); in case you really want to plot the plot handle.